# The constructor Twitter(String, String) is deprecated

Tags: java, android, twitter

I am building a twitter client and when it opens it force closes and the logat shows the exception in OnCreate() method,

what is wrong here

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // find views by id
    buttonUpdate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUpdate);
    textStatus = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textStatus);

    // Add listener
    buttonUpdate.setOnClickListener(this);

    //Initialize twitter
    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String username = prefs.getString("username", "n/a");
    String password = prefs.getString("password", "n/a");
    if (username != null && password != null){
      twitter = new   Twitter(username, password);
    }


}
```

I think it is here in this line

```
      twitter = new   Twitter(username, password);
```

it is under lined and shows "The constructor Twitter(String, String) is deprecated"

what does this mean?

Comment: it means it's not used now or some new methods for available for the same

Answer (score 0):

Twitter no longer supports name/password basic authentication. This constructor is only for non-Twitter sites, such as identi.ca.

You need to use the following method...

```
public Twitter(java.lang.String name,
       Twitter.IHttpClient client)
```

You can find more documentation on this method [here](http://www.winterwell.com/software/jtwitter/javadoc/winterwell/jtwitter/Twitter.html#Twitter%28java.lang.String,%20winterwell.jtwitter.Twitter.IHttpClient%29)